# Port forwarding using Putty

Tags: port-forwarding

I have a server (running ubuntu) where I am running BRAT(http://brat.nlplab.org), which creates a standalone server at http://127.0.0.1:8001. Now I want to access this in my local machine (Windows 10). I am using Putty to access the server. I have read about port forwarding in some blogs but I have no clue how to do it. Is port forwarding the right way to do this or is it something else? Can someone give the commands necessary to make it work? Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts, servers and protocols above OSI layer-4 are all off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. I followed the instructions in https://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_putty.html. The steps I followed are:

1. In Putty go to Tunnels tab in the SSH tab in Connections tab.
2. Add source port and destination. Source port is the port you are
   going to use in local machine which I used as (8002). Destination is the
   port in the server which was :8001.
3. Since the application uses GUI I had to go to X11 tab and enable X11
   forwarding.

This worked for me.